# Getting different results for Mysql round function when used in two different ways

Tags: mysql

I have a column with only one column 'id'. The create statement of the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` float default NULL
);
```

The value present in the table is:

```
id
-----
8.075
```

When I execute the query:

```
SELECT ROUND(id, 2) FROM test;
```

I am getting result '8.07'.
But when I simply execute the query:

```
SELECT ROUND(8.075,2);
```

I am getting value of '8.08'.

What can be done to get the consistent result in both the cases?

The demo of these query can be viewed [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/256b6/2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of a round depends on the implicit type of the literal `8.075`.

The floating point number `8.075` is represented internally as the closest possible float, which is `8.07499999999999928946`, which rounds to 2 places as `8.07`.

If the literal `8.075` is being interpreted as a decimal, then the 'round-half-even' rule is probably being applied.  I'd look it up but MySQL's website is down right now.

Comment: Yes, but then how would you round the numbers like '8.075' (which in mysql is stored as closest possible float '8.07499999999999928946') to get result 8.08 .

Comment: If you need that behavior, then don't use float, use decimal instead.  It is a well-known limitation of floating point numbers that they trade off precision for the ability to represent a much larger range than integers using similar memory sizes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I never knew about decimal earlier. Decimal solved my problem.